# How to show items with the latest count of quantity

Tags: c#, sql

This is tblStocks:

[image: This is tblStocks]

What SQL query will only show the latest count of the item?

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

[image: result should display this]

Comment: A proper sql query will do the job. Try writing it.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: i want to show only the item with the latest quantity. i've researched for sql queries that can help but have found none, even here in stack overflow. have u looked at the picture?

Comment: The SQL database does not store items in the order that the items were written to the database.  So first you need to order by stockId to get latest results.  So you want to order in descending order by stockId and then take Top 1 items.  You also need to Group by ItemName so you get the latest of each item.

Comment: I have posted an answer... Try it

Comment: `SELECT ItemName, SUM([IN])- SUM(OUT) from iTEMS group by ItemName` this should give you the expected output..

Comment: Thanks for all those who answered especially @cdaiga and Chetan Ranpariya. I got the expected output by using this query from cdaiga:
SELECT A.ItemName,StockCount
FROM tblStocks A JOIN
(SELECT MAX(stocksID) stocksID 
FROM tblStocks
GROUP BY ItemName) B
ON A.stocksID=B.stocksID;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ItemName,StockCount
FROM tblStocks A JOIN
(SELECT MAX(stocksID) stocksID 
FROM tblStocks
GROUP BY ItemName) B
ON A.stocksID=B.stocksID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
select ItemName,StockCount
from tblStocks a
where a.stocksID = (select Max(b.stocksID) from tblStocks b where
                   a.ItemName = b.ItemName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming StockTest is you table please check following query 

`WITH tmpStock
    AS (SELECT ItemName,
               MAX(stockId) AS lateststockId
        FROM dbo.StockTest
        GROUP BY ItemName)
    SELECT stockId,
           dbo.StockTest.ItemName,
           stockcount
    FROM tmpStock
        INNER JOIN StockTest
            ON tmpStock.ItemName = StockTest.ItemName
               AND stockId = lateststockId
    ORDER BY StockTest.ItemName;`